# How to prevent a span from breaking into the next line - responsive webdesign?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, line-breaks

Following simple list, where in every h4, there is a span at the end.

```
<ul class="items">
    <li>
        <h4>Prevent LineBreakOfPlus <span class="goto">o</span>
        </h4>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h4>Digital Signage <span class="goto">o</span></h4>
        … 

</ul>
```

Screenshot of the page's source:

[image]

---

The CSS for the `span` looks like this …

```
.items .goto {
   font-family: 'QuaySans-Icons';
   font-size: 1.6em;
   position: relative;
   float: right;
}
```

The final thing looks like this:

[image]

The problem I have with this is that when decreasing the width of the browser window (I'm working on a responsive webdesign) the `span`-icon is breaking into the next line.

[image]

Do you have any creative solution or idea on how to prevent this from happening?

Kind regards and thank you in advance,
Matt

Comment: can "Prevent" and "LineBreakOfPlus" can appear in 2 lines. OR it should only be a single line.

Comment: can you put this into a jsfiddle please

Comment: @MaheshSapkal It can break into two lines. However the the plus should never be separated from the second line if so.

Comment: @Richlewis http://jsfiddle.net/c7H2P/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the icon to keep inline with the last word in your text line, you can simply do:

```
<ul class="items">
    <li>
         <h4>Prevent LineBreakOfPlus<span class="goto">o</span></h4>
    </li>
    <li>
         <h4>Digital Signage<span class="goto">o</span></h4>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and the CSS might be:

```
.items {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.items li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.items h4 {
    margin: 0;
}
.items .goto {
    background-color: gray;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    margin-left: 10px; /* optional */
}
```

If there is no white space between your work and the `span`, the motif will simply follow the word if the `li` element is forced to flow into a second line.

You can use `margin-left` to create visual spacing or insert a `&nbsp` entity before the `span`, quite a few ways to do.  The details depend a bit on what effect you want.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/VsBet/ (two examples of how to do it)

**Keeping Icon Right Justified**

Here is one approach to pinning the icon to the right of the `h4` element:

```
.ex2.items h4 {
    position: relative;
    line-height: 1.5;
    outline: 1px dotted blue;
    padding-right: 2.00em;
}
.ex2.items .goto {
    background-color: wheat;
    line-height: 1.00;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0.0em;
    height: 1.00em;
    width: 1.00em;
    outline: 1px dotted red;
}
```

Use absolute positioning of the `span` to keep it to the right and bottom of `h4`.  If `h4` forms to line, the icon will follow the second line.  You may need to adjust the positioning depending on the icon size.  If you allow the icon to grow in size, you may get other issue in extreme cases.  I might fix the icon to a `px` height or width (or a max value).  Finally, set some `padding-right` in `h4` to prevent the icon from overlapping the text as the window gets smaller.

**Note** I explicitly specified line-height values to accentuate the issue around not knowing the height of the icon.  You may need to adjust these to vertically position the icon.

Answer (score 2):

Decrease your font-size when you have less space. I guess you have the problem in media with max-width:480px.  I found decreasing the font-size a good alternative to keep the design consistent in responsive sites

Answer (score 0):

I've mocked it up on the demo, however it is a bit raw.

```
.items {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    /*width:180px;*/
}
.items li {
    border: 1px solid red;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
}
.items h4 {
    margin:0; padding:0; font-size:16px; padding-right:10px;
}

.items .goto {
    margin-top: -10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/maheshsapkal/naYYf/)**

Check the following link and decrease the width of browser.

**[RESULT](http://jsfiddle.net/maheshsapkal/naYYf/embedded/result/)**